# issue after updating the deleted branch

Tags: git, github

I created a PR in some repo and I deleted that branch from local. After a while(when few commits were merged in the repo) I wanted to do changes in the PR, so I created the branch with the same name and pulled all the changes and added more commits. But as soon as I pushed the changes it showed all the commits of the repo(around 3k commits).

I guess the problem is, initially the branch was created with different state of `master` and when I again created the branch it was in a different state of `master`, so as soon as I pushed, all the differences were reflected in the PR as 3k commits.

Now I want to get out of this problem. I want only my commits of the PR to be shown. How is it possible?

Comment: For ref see [this](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/12147)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

First find your old commits with

`git log --after="2014-7-1" --before="2014-7-4" --author="John"`

You can find more info about formatting log output [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-log).

In your local branch reset the HEAD to your old commits and cherry pick the new commits

 `git reset <old commit ID>`

 `git stash; git stash drop`

 `git cherry-pick <new commit ID's>`

 `git push -f <remote> <branch-name>`

This will create your PR to have only your old commits and new ones. Essentially you are removing all the commits from master in your branch.

Your analysis seems to be right. The master was in a different state from when you created the PR.

Although you didn't need to create a new branch after pulling. You had deleted the branch in your local repo, not remote.

You could have done a `git pull` and `git checkout <branch-name>` and the branch would be recreated in your local repo in the same state you left it in.

Comment: It's strange but I am unable to find my old commits. I used `git log`. Do the commits vanish if `merge pull` has been done? I don't know why it is not showing.

Comment: The commits wouldn't have vanished, but there are so many commits, I understand it might be difficult to find them.  I've updated my answer to search for the commits.

Answer (score 1):

I think your conclusion is correct. You seem to have pushed all the changes from master to your branch.

I’ll make some assumptions before I continue:

- you branched out of master in the first place
- you want to merge your branch to master at some point in the future
  They’re mostly for the third solution I’ve listed.

Couple of ways of getting out of this that I can think of:

- create a new branch out of master and cherry pick all the commits from the original state of your pr and the changes you have made. However this might be problematic if you had a lot of changes to cherry pick and/or the changes you’ve made later were conflicting with the older changes because of intermediate changes to master branch.
- clone the repo, checkout the branch at the latest commit from before you pushed new changes to it, try to force pushed the branch (I assume no one else has pushed their own changes to that branch) and then apply your changes. Potential problems: well “force push” usually works better in the Star War universe rather than in git...
- merge master into your branch. Assuming your end goal is to get the branch merged to master at some point, this might be the sanest option. Problems: in my experience github PR diff preview sometimes get confused and keeps showing changes that are already in master after doing something like that. Usually creating a new pr helps with that. Another obvious problem would be any changes from master affecting the files edited on the branch - conflicts or simply obscuring intent.

There’s probably also some way of wriggling your way out of this using reverts, but that would not be my first option (maybe you’ll get some other answer with that solution). My suggestion is the last one I listed above - merge master to your branch (all assumptions considered).

Phew, sorry if it was too verbose, but hopefully it will help you out. Curious to see other answers as well.